# Unwanted swipe RL to LR on mobile screen sizes

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am developing a responsive UI for web project with Google Chrome's `inspect element`. Everything was fine until the screen is re-sized to `640px` and below.

The images shows that the `Swipe Left to Right and vice versa` has just been enabled? Or something like that.

I have tried removing all the paddings and margins, but the `"Black-Margin-Like"` is still there.
How can I remove that Swipe LR to RL effect, or whatever they call it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is good question, however, you have to regard the CSS code that you have or regard an online demo on [tag:jsbin] or [tag:jsfiddle].

Comment: @sємsєм I think I got the reason why it is happening. I have some element below ( `<li>` ) that has a fixed width, and it overlaps the edge of the page. I will try to solved it first and get back when it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the very reason of this behavior.
The reason is the overlapping elements.
For those who may stumble on this problem, try my approach on finding the overlapping elements.
Add this to your css file:

```
body * {
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #000000;
}
```

Adding that css styles will enable you to see the elements that causes RL to LR swipe because of extra width.

Happy coding!